# How to make EF map NavigationProperty on one entity to Collection of the other

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1

I want a straightforward foreign key relationship between two entities, with EF properties going both ways. However, at the moment EF is generating 2 foreign keys representing each direction of the relationship. How can I make EF treat them as a single property? The below generates two database foreign key constraints named Script_ScriptRuns and ScriptRun_Script, using foreign key field Script_Id and Script_Id1 respectively

```cs
public class Script
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ScriptRun> ScriptRuns { get; set; }
}


public class ScriptRun
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Script Script { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you posted, it only created a single FK for me - Script_Id in the `ScriptRun` class.

Are you simply wanting to rename the FK that's getting created in that class? You can do that by mapping the column in your DbContext.  This would map it to ScriptId:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Script>()
            .HasMany(s => s.ScriptRuns)
            .WithRequired(sc => sc.Script)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ScriptId"));
```

If not, can you post your entire model?

Comment: Perfect just what I needed - the `HasMany`/`WithRequired` combination appears to be sufficient to tell EF the two are the same. Cheers! SO currently telling me I need to wait 3 mins to accept answer, will do so then.